# Multicast Socket Not Receiving After Disabling/Enabling Network Connection

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, multicast

I'm using Socket with following configuration to receive multicast packets and the code is working properly.

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.Bind(bindPoint);
socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(multicastAddress, IPAddress.Any));
socket.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
```

But after disabling the network connection from Control Panel and enabling, the socket cannot receive the multicast data. I can see the packets with Wireshark. I tried closing the socket, resetting he socket but restarting is the only solution I came up with. The application will be used in an environment where the user typically remove the ethernet cable and plug another one.

Initially I was using UdpClient but the same problem persists on that too. The operating system is Windows 7 and I use .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: Pretty sure that this is normal.  Consider testing it the way your user should do this, messing with cables does not require disabling the adapter.

Comment: have you try to do ipconfig /release before  to reconnect..just to check if not the cause..?

Answer (score 0):

After disabling a network connection, Windows automatically uses another connection if you have one (virtual host etc.). After enabling the previous connection, the application doesn't use the correct connection since there were no interface selection made. Disabling other connections or specifying the interface solves the problem.